# Problem in concatenating 3 datasets with same column names and values being replaced for the same key column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate 3 datasets with same 4 column names and the resultant set is not what I am expecting. The datasets look like
**dataset A  **

```
| Col_A  | Col_B |Col_C | Col_D|
| ------ | ------|------|------|
| a10    | b10   |      |      |
| a11    | b11   |      |      |      
| a12    | b12   | 10   | 11   |
| a13    | b13   |      |      |
```

**dataset B  **

```
| Col_A | Col_B |Col_C | Col_D|
| ------| ----- |------|------|
| a10    | b10  | 12   |  13  |
| a11    | b11  | 15   | 16   |
| a12    | b12  |      |      |
| a13    | b13  |      |      |
```

**dataset C  **

```
| Col_A | Col_B |Col_C | Col_D|
| ----- | ----- |------|------|
| a10   | b10   |      |      |
| a11   | b11   |      |      |
| a12   | b12   |17    | 18   |
| a13   | b13   |20    |  21  |
```

Resultant dataset I need to look like is after concatenating the datasets in the sequence:

**dataset final  **

```
| Col_A | Col_B |Col_C | Col_D|
| ----- | ----- |------|------|
| a10   | b10   |12    |   13 |
| a11   | b11   | 15   |  16  |
| a12   | b12   | 17   | 18   |
| a13   | b13   | 20   |  21  |
```

I tried the normal `concat()` method but I am not able to solve the part where the values are being replaced when concatenation done in the sequence.

```
concat_all = pd.concat([df_A,df_B,df_C], axis =0)
```

Recreating the datasets:

```
import pandas as pd

dfA = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col_A': ['a10', 'a11', 'a12', 'a13'],
    'Col_B': ['b10', 'b11', 'b12', 'b13'],
    'Col_C': ['', '', '10', ''],
    'Col_D': ['', '', '11', '']
})

dfB = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col_A': ['a10', 'a11', 'a12', 'a13'],
    'Col_B': ['b10', 'b11', 'b12', 'b13'],
    'Col_C': ['12', '15', '', ''],
    'Col_D': ['13', '16', '', '']
})

dfC = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col_A': ['a10', 'a11', 'a12', 'a13'],
    'Col_B': ['b10', 'b11', 'b12', 'b13'],
    'Col_C': ['', '', '17', '20'],
    'Col_D': ['', '', '18', '21']
})
```

Any leads would be appreciated

Comment: The columns in your dataset values don't seem to match the headings. Please fix it up. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support for how to format tables.

Comment: `concat` doesn't "merge" dataframes, it grows them. I would set the index to `[Col_A, Col_B]` and use `pandas.combine_first`

Comment: Also, I would read through the pandas tag wiki page to learn how to ask good pandas questions: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info

Right now,  I wouldn't expect too much help since anyone who might want to experiment with your problem will have to manually type in your data.

Comment: @Barmar
corrected the format of table now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
df = (pd.concat([dfA, dfB, dfC], axis=0)
        .query('Col_C != ""')
        .groupby(['Col_A', 'Col_B'])
        .agg({'Col_C': 'last', 'Col_D': 'last'}))

            Col_C Col_D
Col_A Col_B            
a10   b10      12    13
a11   b11      15    16
a12   b12      17    18
a13   b13      20    21
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my question block and making it easy readable format. Your solution definitely helped my problem as you have shown your output.